# Configuration settings for Omniauth to Google in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am using **Omniauth 1.0.1** in my Rails app for authentication. I have "**omniauth-google-oauth2**"  gem for Google provider. But it shows me the error as

`rescue in provider': Could not find matching strategy for :google. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-google). (LoadError).

I gave "**provider :google, 'domain.com', 'secret', :scope => 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/'**" in my initializers. 
Could u please tell me what went wrong? 
Thank u.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
:google_oauth2
```

as your provider.

Comment: I tried as `provider :google_oauth2, 'google_key', 'google_secret', :scope => 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/'`. In my gem file `gem 'omniauth' 
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'` Now having error says `No route matches auth/google`. But the call back is working fine for twitter. Could u please tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.0, omniauth has taken out the individual strategies into separate gems. For more info, visit [omniauth's page](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth), and/or listen to eg this excellent [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity).

Comment: Ya. I have added "omniauth-google-oauth2" strategy as described in Omniauth's page. But still having this error.